# A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed for outlook by using access token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, outlook, jakarta-mail, imap

we are trying to login outlook.com in our app by using oauth2.0, we have done the registration of app AAD.
App authenticates the user successfully and responds with the access_token, now further we wanted to read the emails from imap server and here we are getting failure, please try and help us out with this.

Kindly find below error we are getting.

- OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [UABOADIAUABSADAAMQBDAEEAMAAwADYAMgAuAEkATgBEAFAAUgBEADAAMQAuAFAAUgBPAEQALgBPAFUAVABMAE8ATwBLAC4AQwBPAE0A]
  A0 CAPABILITY
- CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
  A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
  DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
  DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
  DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=siccsanda@outlook.com, password=
  DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism PLAIN disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable
  DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
  DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism NTLM not supported by server
  A1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1zaWNjc2FuZGFAb3V0bG9vay5jb20BYXV0aD1CZWFyZXIgRXdCd0E4bDZCQUFVNms3K1hWUXprR3lNdjdWSEIvaDRjSGJKWVJBQUFhbWdZWE81azJ2NEVQYmduSE5BWUcyNENWYXJ4V2dEek9lZ2E2S0J0SGZKcDVkV1hkK3E5T2ExSEJocitIQW1JWVJBRkh6NWxFRWJJRFdGZVF6MGU5U0pRNzZzVnYwUVhXVFFRRUExSktRSmdHdm51Z3QrV2dvd1pJUUxmcVJBQmh2Mm02WWk4bDlWU1FGS1pzV2lpY000blYzWElza0RyYWlWRTNjU2ZMS0tmK09MUDg4OHNCNnVPbzlOWDNXYnZFWUdZTGVMbVpjUG5NOUlrK3MzazhYQWtpOWY2VTl6MGFjUHdKQWRsbk9JZElvNzJQYjhYeXJmVDB6OHpFV2ExRm8xVVpiUHJvdnIrakd1NTJhcjMyaVlZWnpkSDhxaGhZRFRFcTJOQnhOUDVaV1dsbTZQV2lYR2ZhZ05EL2k3RWxDSFJRZ0twdFN2dDMySEpaN3VqRkFEWmdBQUNDYTdqZGVnM3cza1FBSUdpR09YREFaYmdhK3ZDempqeERwT29wZExERTQzaldhbHRVSHJDVk8zS1BSMFFzMzV5SDNTeWNaK0xqTEl1U043VVZheWozUHZWejZ1bDZPdkxkSUozVkhpcjBBbTRxeDlvWjRobnBLRG0yc2Q2akptUWxtVFFHRmhqTjVLN0poSmUyb1VvMzJZNHlrYU1vNFRPQkpxc3ZuOCtja0dCekRHYUdsWjltU0dsZmpJWDdIR29HbnQ4S2NmOEhsTFdnSzhpVWkvOWJoTjV4MnNNSWM0YzhWWlRlUkpJbXNrQUNQbnRoSGoybUNHeXpmRi9qTXkvbnV4VFNOVE0wby9QS045ME00M1VGT3hDSk5MRldiVkkwQ3RzcDNWRGZ6MWVZejdZV1NtLzNtSlhkSk02bkFIeWZRQnFJZTB3Q3A1aU9pU1J2R3pyV0o1WXlVRWNWV1VyRndxQjBQbXFUMEJFeVBOOVhLR0FZQmlFQ2hEanpqS1NjUFRNM29jbEdCQld6V0FNYzF4bUVXTktsSm5Ma0s3N3Z3S2NkYklTa1c1WWdBbU84ZWZrUExIdU16UnpuQ2o3NTQzS0dCOEpFUTlZSUx0TkJQMTZmcjFYR1NnVkFwb2tkUU1wdG1YU2dFd2pJZnozKzgrWDE0MFJqblZaYjdrbzBQNnJsQzNnWkRVdEdoQ3I2Mm15ZzN2U1pZaUt2UzBrVkR2ZDhFbUJ3N1BUZGVlWFZEWXZYc2gycTJMY2NleEVhOXJuSHFra1g4cVVRNWp2U2RvT2JTL3VGM1hZL1VuajlHZUFhbERCdEZvUXhsREkvaU5aeGVoS2FFSDFydE5ncTI2by9oSW1NNzZDb3BwcCtzb0p3dUJQNE5wbDFHY1RQNEdycjFURVkwbGRTTW4zNDdwODE2WEZJWk1FSVJiSEpoekR6VVNIRVQxbjFRbEZyOUhRZlVVSHhCOWtPMWlzVzdEaDdaSFhMSnBBRCtiTHc3SGpuY3JYcHBXdkEydFRzclNWVVkwSDhJS2lpU0hBZz09AQE=
  A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.

Please find thecode for connection:

```
 properties.put("mail.imaps.host", "outlook.office365.com");
        properties.put("incomingHost", "outlook.office365.com");
        properties.put("outgoingHost", "smtp.office365.com");
        properties.put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
        //properties.put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
       // properties.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
        //properties.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
        properties.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
       
        this.store = session.getStore("imaps");
     store.connect("outlook.office365.com", "abc@outlook.com", "access_token");
```

Comment: did u find any solution.. for this..! looking for the same

Comment: Found any solution for this?